# Rails 2.1 belongs_to primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a basic database with a structure like this.

```
products
------------------
id
serial

order
------------------
id
product_serial
```

Unfortunately, I cannot change structure of the DB. I looked at the docs for Rails 2.1 and it said I could setup a relationship like this.

```
belongs_to :product,
           :class_name => 'Product',
           :foreign_key => 'product_serial',
           :primary_key => 'serial'
```

However, that gives me this error.

```
Unknown key: primary_key
```

Without the primary key it produces this SQL

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE (`products`.`id` = #{serial})
```

How do I setup a `belongs_to` relationship on this?

**EDIT** For the record, I am working in Rails 2.1. (I know, don't tell me).

Comment: You don't need to specify the `:class_name` as this is inferred from the relation.

Comment: Sorry, should not have included that. I already had a method named `product` so I was using a shortened name and thus required the class name.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [available options for the `belongs_to` association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference) for the Rails 2 branch, you'll see that `:primary_key` is not one of them.

It should be enough, in your case, to simply state the foreign key as you did in the previous line.

Comment: Not so in Rails 4: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

Comment: OP is using Rails 2, that was also the docs version I linked to in my answer.

Comment: Odd, I looked it up on APIDoc: http://apidock.com/rails/v2.1.0/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to and am now confused. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `order` model does not have a field (and thus method) which is called `serial`. You don't need to specify it, then it defaults to `id` (which you do have).